# Shutting down computer during dropbox synchronization

Tags: internet, sync, dropbox, upload

What will happen when I shut down my computer during uploading a file via DropBox app for Windows and then start the computer again?

Will it upload the whole file again or only the part that wasn't uploaded before?

Comment: DropBox to my knowledge does not support block file transferring in the first place, which means the server  only receives the file when the transfer is complete, the entire file will be uploaded at the next chance it has.

Comment: You can test this. Take a 100MB file, sync it and monitor how long it takes. Then take another 100MB file, not the same though, and upload it until about 90% is done. Then shutdown dropbox or restart your computer. Then try again and see if it takes about the same time, or significantly less time.

Comment: Checking when it reaches 90% will be a bit hard because DropBox app doesn't show the percentage. It only shows how many minutes are left. And that is also not accurate because I have a slow upload link and the upload speed varies a lot.

Comment: Task manager network tab can show how much bandwidth an application has used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropbox uses chunks to upload files in segments. When a file transfer is aborted, it will reupload the chunks that were not uploaded succesfully, but not the whole file.

See also [dropbox api: chunkeduploader](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.ChunkedUploader.html)

Comment: I would guess they have a cache, much like the local cache Dropbox uses: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/328. That is, after a certain time period has passed they may delete partially uploaded files from their server (otherwise it'd be there taking up space indefinitely with no way for the user to delete it).